# creating a web based download manager

Tags: java, php, web, download-manager, nas

I want to create a webbased download manager for one-click-hosters like rapidshare. Similar to PyLoad (http://pyload.org/) but i want to make some significant changes and make it much easier.

First i thought i could just grab a MVC-Framework and start coding but then I realized that the app have to work without being connected to it. So I need something like a continious running service. The app should work on a linux NAS.

I just have no idea how to start and what I exacetly need for this.
An use-case could be: open browser and point to web-app and add some links. Then starting to download and closing the browser. After some time the downloads should be finished and I can repeat the use-case.

The programming language isnt that important but i prefer java, javascript or php. But what technologies do I need? Web Services? Daemons? Sockets? How can I accomplish the "always running service" on the service?

I am thankful for any keywords.

Comment: First get a VPS then install apache on it and IDM then command from your php code to your IDM. So simply

Comment: Basically I want to download from the one click hoster share-online and they provide an API for it. So I thought i just could write a small downloader for it. Also for learning purposes.

Comment: Sockets in php will help you but for big sized file due to cpu lacks u must write an algirithm to divide file to parts.

Comment: well, I will do it now with a socket on the server-side. Any Client can connect then to the server and check the progres of the download and the client can disconnect again.

Comment: So complicated. Use asp instead

Comment: and how would that be better?

Comment: Check this http://marvinlee.wordpress.com/2007/08/08/make-your-own-java-download-manager/